# Isolator resistance on external radiation dependency

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electrical-resistance, semiconductor-physics

Considering a silicon (but also any isolator), that has band gap $E_g = 1.12 eV$ at $T = 300K$, do I understand correctly, that by shining on just a piece of silicon with at least infrared radiation ($1.1\mu m$), then, at least its surface will be conductive?

If yes, does it mean, that just a piece of silicon laying on the desk on the day, being shined by sun with visible light that’s energy is higher silicon’s band gap already makes it conductive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, indeed, illuminating an insulator/semiconductor excites some of the electrons from the valence band to the conduction band, making the material conductive (since now there are conduction electrons and holes present, free to move under the application of electric field.)

This is notably the mechanism behind the [photodetectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photodetector) and [solar cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_cell).

Comment: So, I assume this is the reason, why IR indicators have dark screen in front of them — this screen blocks most of visible light, that will also excite detector and pass only IR radiation, maybe even only some specter.

Comment: I mean, one additional question I want to ask, is if some atom is in state 1, and it receives an energy that equals not 1-2, but 1-3, then atom will be excited already to third state, right?

Comment: @Stdugnd4ikbd yes, indeed - it is excited to the state of matching energy: $E_n-E_1=\hbar\omega$, where $\omega$ is the photon frequency. When the frequencies do not match, we still may have Rayleigh scattering, Raman scattering or multiphoton absorption (although all these are considered higher-order processes, neglected in the first approximation.)